# package.xml: use 'replace' tag for non-ROS package

Tags: ros, package.xml, ros-kinetic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I do this:

```
foo/package.xml:
...
<replace>bar</replace>
...
```

I get this:

```
$ dpkg-deb --info ros-kinetic-foo_0.1.0_amd64.deb
...
 Replaces: ros-kinetic-bar
...
```

What do I do if I *don't* want that `ros-kinetic-` prefix on the replaced package name?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317627/package.xml:-use-%27replace%27-tag-for-non-ros-package/) by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 193 on 2019-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
I believe that `ros-kinetic-` prefix is added there by the `rosdebian` generator in Bloom. I'm not sure it can be removed.

Perhaps @William can add something here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
`REP 127` does say this though ([here](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#replace-multiple)):

> Declares a rosdep key or ROS package name that your package replaces

"rosdep key" could only mean "system dependency" (ie: non-ROS pkg), so it would seem this *should* work.

Is `bar` a ROS pkg?

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-03-06**:
@gvdhoorn , in this example, `bar` need not be a ROS package. It's better (for my use case, at least) if `bar` is *not* a ROS package. This would allow me to `<replace>` arbitrary packages by name and not just the proper subset of packages known to `rosdep`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Hm.

I can think of one reason why we would not want to do/support/allow this (but this is just me speculating): if arbitrary pkgs could be replaced that way, I would create a "rogue" `package.xml`, release it and replace any arbitrary pkg on a system. That wouldn't be very nice.

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-03-06**:
...unless, of course, that was the desired behavior. Any person (or software tool) capable of creating and/or editing a `debian/control` file can effect package removal. Maintainers and system administrators are responsible for package hygiene and installation, respectively.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
In principle I agree. But we have to remember that releasing a ROS pkg and getting it distributed through the package repositories to thousands of user's machines is way easier than getting something into Debian/Ubuntu -- which have stricter quality control mechanisms.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
But again: it was just me speculating.

What you've observed could just be a bug in the generator.

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-03-06**:
Submitted issue asking for clarification: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/520

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-03-06**:
I assume `bar` isn't a `rosdep` key in your case? Have you tried using an existing `rosdep` key? I would expect that to get resolved to whatever system package(s) the rosdep db maps it to on the target platform.

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-03-06**:
I have not tried using an existing `rosdep` key because the package I want to replace is not a ROS package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The strings used for dependencies are *not* system packages. Every name is a rosdep key which is then resolves by the `rosdep` database to a actual package name. So even if your package is not a ROS package you need a rosdep key for it in order to be able to use it in the manifest.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rubicks](https://answers.ros.org/users/38175/rubicks/) on 2019-03-06**:
@dirk-thomas, okay, that explains it. I'll see if I can work around this with some `rosdep` trickery and (if successful) post an answer. Thanks very much for clarifying.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
I'd actually assumed that @rubicks was already using recognised `rosdep` keys, but if that wasn't the case then that would indeed explain it.